# Formatting MDY dates as MY

Tags: excel, date, format, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a formatting issue with dates in Excel 2013. I'm from Argentina and I have the English version of Windows 7 with the Argentinean date format `dd/mm/yyyy`. I have 5,000 lines with dates with the USA format `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS`. For some reason when I try to give format to these dates Excel thinks they are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. That messes up all the formatting.

I'm trying to obtain `mm/yyyy`.

Is there any way to use a formula to obtain that format? Instead of using Excel common formatting.

Comment: Where do these dates come from?

Answer (score 3):

If all the formatting is consistent then:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,1,2),MID(A1,4,2))+RIGHT(A1,8)
```

copied down should convert from USA (strings in ColumnA) to UK format and yield results that Excel recognises as date/time serial numbers (so may be formatted mm/yyyy).